# Get all elements with given key in multidimensional array to a onedimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Suppose I have the a multidimensional array with keys **id** and **field**. All I want is to put all elements of **id** in onedimensional array. By this I mean "erase" field but keep the original multidimensional array intact... is this possible without using a *foreach*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like the purpose [array_column()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) was added to PHP

```
$result = array_column($myOriginalArray, 'id');
```

but that does require PHP 5.5+

If you're running an earlier version of PHP, you can simulate this using

```
$columnName = 'id';
$result = array_map(
    function($value) use ($columnName) {
        return $value[$columnName];
    },
    $myOriginalArray
);
```